# how to close the Client Connection and return the Call in NETMQ?

Tags: c#, zeromq, netmq

I am just Started Using NETMQ REQ/RES pattern to send and receive the request response from both ends. Client is from IIS and server is from windows service. My question is when i had stopped the service and tried a client request. The client went to infinite LOOP and doesnt return.

**Server Code**

```
using (var server = new ResponseSocket())
{
    server.Bind("tcp://10.150.0.242:5556");
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            // using (var client = ctx.CreateRequestSocket())
            {
                string fromClientMessage = server.ReceiveString();
                string result = DigitalSignInitialization(fromClientMessage);
                server.Send(result);
                Console.WriteLine("From Client: {0}", fromClientMessage);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception Ex) { server.Send("Failure"); }

    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
using (NetMQContext ctx = NetMQContext.Create())
{ 
     using (var client = ctx.CreateRequestSocket())
     {
         //try
        // {
        //client.Connect("tcp://10.150.0.242:5556");
        client.Connect(strNCODE_ADDRESS);
                    client.Send(json);

        fromServerMessage = client.ReceiveString(new TimeSpan (0, 0, 0, 30));
                                    if(fromServerMessage != "Success")
        {
            fromServerMessage="Failure";

            return "<RESULT><DIGITAL_SIGNATURE>DIgital Signature Failed</DIGITAL_SIGNATURE></RESULT>";
        }
    }
}
```

Code cant able to return .
Please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. 0MQ sockets does not fail if other endpoint disconnects. Instead socket `Send` method will await until server became available. If it is not desired behavior you should either use `dontWait` argument of the `Send` method or redesign entire approach in polling data from server.

Comment: How Poller can work in the absense of server. will it return client immediately about server not running/ able communicate.